Lindbladian superoperator decomposition
this question is about the equation that describes the open quantum system.
"The general stochastic evolution of an open quantum system can be modelled by
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \mathcal{L}(\rho),
\end{equation}
where the superoperator $\mathcal{L}(\rho)$ can be decomposed as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\rho) = \sum_i g_i S_i \rho T_i^{\dagger},
\end{equation}
with unitary operator $S_i \text{ and } T_i$, and coefficients $g_i$."
This is part of the paper titled "Theory of variational quantum simulation".
The paper does not say what the superporator is, but I believe the superoperator $\mathcal{L}(\rho)$ should be expressed as
$$\mathcal{L}(\rho) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\rho] + \sum_j \gamma_j \left(L_j \rho L_j^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}\lbrace L_j^{\dagger} L_j,\rho \rbrace \right)$$
which is the RHS of the Lindblad master equation.
My question is, can we always decompose the superoperator $\mathcal{L}(\rho)$ as $\mathcal{L}(\rho) = \sum_i g_i S_i \rho T_i^{\dagger}$? I think that $g_i, S_i \text{, and } T_i$ might not always exist.

Please do not use images of text and mathematics.  The site standard is Mathjax, and I note you used it for some of your question

Oh, I didn't realize that. I modified it to manually type out all the text and equations from the image.

If the Lindblad master equation is what is had in mind by the authors of the paper and by you, then the claim "The general stochastic evolution of an open quantum system can be modeled by..." is strictly speaking incorrect. The most general differential equation modeling Markovian dynamics is given by the Lindblad master equation. Markovian dynamics is a subset of all possible open quantum dynamics.

So you mean if L(\rho) is the RHS of the Lindblad master equation (what I imagined in the question), then it only works for Markovian dynamics, not for every open quantum dynamics. Am I understand correctly?

Do you think it is still possible to decompose the superoperator L(\rho) as described in above question, even if we do not restrict the evolution to be Markovian one?

Let me extend the existing answers addressing the unitarity of $S_i$ and $T_i$ as asked for in OP's question. From @E. Anikin's answer, we have $\mathcal{L}(O) = \sum_i g_i S_i O T_i^\dagger$. You can always find a basis of the space of operators with unitaries as basis states. Since the paper in OP's question is on quantum simulation, you could for instance use a decomposition into Pauli operators. This way, the sum in $\mathcal{L}$ eventually blows up (in this sense, it is not a minimal decomposition). but we can replace $S_i$ and $T_i$ by their Pauli decompositions. This means you can always find a set of unitaries $S_i$ and $T_i$ to write the Lindbladian in the desired form.

A superoperator is a linear operator acting on the space of operators (let us denote it $V$). Therefore, any superoperator can be represented as a matrix $\mathcal{L}_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta}$, where it acts on operator with a matrix $O_{\alpha\beta}$ as
$$
(\mathcal{L}(O))_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_{kl}\mathcal{L}_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta} O_{\gamma\delta}.
$$
It is easy to see that the space of $\mathcal{L}_{ij,kl}$ is isomorphic to a tensor product $V\otimes V$ (sorry, I don't care here about the difference between $V$ and its conjugate space). Any element of a $V\otimes V$ can be expressed as a sum over tensor products of elements of $V$, so
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta} = \sum_i S^i_{\alpha\gamma} (T^i_{\delta\beta})^*.
$$
Combining two above equations, we get just
$$
(\mathcal{L}(O)) = 
\sum_i S_i O T_i^\dagger.
$$
We can also change the normalization of $O$ and $T$ arbitrarily to get some constants $g_i$, so finally
$$
\mathcal{L}(O)) = 
\sum_i g_j S_i O T_i^\dagger.
$$

Yes, even more, $S_i$ and $T_i$ can be chosen the same. This mapping is known as a Kraus decomposition: it is the generalisation of a unitary transformation that includes decoherence.
The Kraus decomposition is also known to be a completely positive trace-preserving map, meaning it maps density matrices to density matrices.
The Lindblad equation is the continuous version of this trace-preserving map; for an infinitesimal timestep you could have for example $S_i=\sqrt{dt}L_i$ and $S_0=1-dt\sum_j L_i^\dagger L_i$.
After a finite evolution time, the result is still a completely positive trace-preserving map, so the decomposition should exist in principle, although I don't have an immediate clean expression for it from the top of my head.
CAVEAT: I have assumed open quantum systems means a Markovian one, where the Lindblad equation is actually valid. More general cases of open quantum systems, with an environment that is not memory-free, exist too and their situation is more complicated.
EDIT: I missed that $S_i$ and $T_i$ have to be unitary. This is not necessarily the case for the Kraus decomposition, so choosing them the same may not be allowed in general.

Oh, I missed the unitarity of $S_i$ and $T_i$ too.
